# Parameter unassigned error in OMNeT++ and INET examples on installation

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have installed OMNeT++ 5.6.2 and added the INET 4.2.1 framework.
I followed the setup instructions as per the doc given and compiled and did make.
On running ./aloha I seem to encounter parameter unassigned error as follows :

```
Setting up Cmdenv...

Loading NED files from .:  4

Preparing for running configuration General, run #0...
Assigned runID=General-0-20201227-14:11:08-9189
Setting up network "Aloha"...

<!> Error: The simulation wanted to ask a question, set cmdenv-interactive=true to allow it: "Enter parameter 'Aloha.host[0].iaTime' (unassigned):" -- in module (aloha::Host) Aloha.host[0] (id=3), during network setup

End.
```

Even on running a different example from INET, from examples, adhoc, seem to get a similar error as follows :

```
Preparing for running configuration General, run #0...
Assigned runID=General-0-20201223-00:37:38-95889
Setting up network "Net80211"...

<!> Error: The simulation wanted to ask a question, set cmdenv-interactive=true to allow it: "Enter parameter 'Net80211.numHosts' (unassigned):" -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) Net80211 (id=1), during network setup

End.

Simulation terminated with exit code: 1
```

I did set cmdenv-intercative=true in the config file and yet the error does not go away.

Please do let me know if you need any additional information. Any help, direction or pointer to some resources would be greatly appreciated and will be really really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set "cmdenv-intercative=true" for the [General] section.

Comment: Thank you so much! Where is the [General] section ? Is it part of the config file ?

Comment: It is part of the Initialization file (ini file).

Comment: Thank you so much! I added that and it did fix that error! Thank you so much!

Comment: However, on building using :  ./configure WITH_TKENV=no WITH_QTENV=yes WITH_OSG=no  ; and then make, I get the following error : This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa"
in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
zsh: abort      ./aloha